# Can the page load time depend on incidence of visiting?

Tags: performance

Is it possible that page which is not visited frequently requires more time to first load after an activity than the site which is visited often?

I have a one particular page which is visited from different PC's and it loads fast. But when I don’t use this page for a while it loads slower. In both cases I have disabled browsers caching

Comment: What's the context behind this? Note that the functionality of the page has a huge bearing on its performance, and without knowing what this page does it's near impossible to answer, you're going to need to be much more specific

Comment: First of all this site is not cached. It is a simple blog build with something about 10 posts and same static pages.

Comment: And you're sure your web host is not caching things for you? It sounds like this could just be the impact of browser cache

Comment: I am pretty sure that the web host is not caching, however I am not 100% sure. When I disable the browser cache the website is loading fast.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you have a caching plugin installed then a page that is not visited often might not be cached for a while, or the cache could expire between visits. In that case the next visit would require the cached page to be regenerated, which will be much slower than loaded the cached version. But any visits after that should be faster, at least until the cache expires (how long that will take depends on your settings).